# Testing that a string DOES NOT have specific characteristics in a small program (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will ask the user to input a string in all uppercase that ends with a period. Then have it come back with responses when the input doesn't meet the criteria. I understand how to check if it has a characteristic like uppercase I don't however understand how to check if it **does not** have a characteristic. This was my attempt using the != (as in, if the string does not = uppercase) but it didn't work. Thanks for any input, I'm very new so sorry if this is a dumb question.

```
 """Making sure they use uppercase and end with a period"""

s = input("Please enter an upper-case string ending with a period: ")

if s.isupper() and s.endswith("."):
     print("Input meets both requirements.") 
elif s!=upper():
     print ("Input is not all upper case.")
elif s!=endswith("."):
    print ("Input does not end with a period.")
else :
     print ("You just don't want to do this, do you?")
```

Comment: `elif not s.isupper()`. Not negates the outcome of isupper. That's it.

Comment: Thanks @RedX   I feel silly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `not` will reverse the logical statement

`not True` --> `False`

`not False` --> `True`

Here is the code:

```
"""Making sure they use uppercase and end with a period"""

s = input("Please enter an upper-case string ending with a period: ")

if s.isupper() and s.endswith("."):
     print("Input meets both requirements.") 
elif not s.isupper():  #not False -> True
     print ("Input is not all upper case.")
elif not s.endswith("."): #not False -> True
    print ("Input does not end with a period.")
else :
     print ("You just don't want to do this, do you?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to check if it *does not equal* uppercase --- that doesn't make sense anyway, because "uppercase" is an abstract notion that can't be equal to any particular string.  You want to check if `isupper()` is not true.  Just do `elif not s.upper()` and then `elif not s.endswith(".")`.

Comment: Ya it seemed silly to try to use does not equal but for some reason my head was stuck on that and couldn't see a different way. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Just made few adjustments to your code.

```
s = raw_input("Please enter an upper-case string ending with a period: ")

if s.isupper() and s.endswith('.'):
    print("Input meets both requirements.") 
elif not s.isupper():
     print ("Input is not all upper case.")
elif not s.endswith("."):
    print ("Input does not end with a period.")
else :
     print ("You just don't want to do this, do you?")
```

When checking for not upper case or not ends with '.', you should not use != operator here. Because, both of these methods isupper() and endswith() returns booleans. Therefore to check if it is not True, you only have to use not operator.

Comment: Thanks for the input, got it all fixed and running now :)